# How to get ResourceBundle files out of classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, resourcebundle

I am using a `ResourceBundle` for different languages (en, de, fr, ...) and the Keys are listed in a .properties file. It works great, but only using the classpath in the function `getBundle()`.

Now, if I build my project as an executable JAR file, I can't maintain those properties/dictionary files. How can I go on to get those files out of the JAR file and use them (probably with a relative path)?

Comment: put files inside the jar

Comment: The properties files are in the JAR, so I can't maintain them in there. I need to get them out of the JAR to edit those files.

Comment: Edit in the project and rebuild jar

Comment: As the other comments imply - this is an unusual use case. Is this just for development purposes? Normally language resources are fixed at the point they are delivered to the end user, so they tend to end up in the JAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/432762/java/java/absolute-path-bundle-file) if it's helpful. The thread lists a way to achieve this using **absolute** path (not relative).

Inlining the code from link:

```
File file = new File("/languages");
URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("english", Locale.getDefault(), loader);
```

Also from URLs:

```
    URL[] urls = new URL[1];
 
    // - startfolder on the server, where he can find the package-structure like this.BUNDLE_NAME (http://somedomain.com/jws-stuff/com/myexample/test/)
    urls[0] = new URL("http://somedomain.com/jws-stuff/"); 
    ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, Locale.GERMAN, loader);
```

Comment: in case the link does not work in future: File file = new File("C:\\languages");
URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("english", Locale.getDefault(), loader);

Comment: Even a way to make it load from URL for regular apps (non jnlp): URL[] urls = new URL[1];
 
            // - startfolder on the server, where he can find the package-structure like this.BUNDLE_NAME (http://somedomain.com/jws-stuff/com/myexample/test/)
            urls[0] = new URL("http://somedomain.com/jws-stuff/"); 
            ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
 
            RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, Locale.GERMAN, loader);